# I want to create a solver for "Number block puzzles" using ZDD

Tags: python, algorithm

I am developing a puzzle generator and solver for Calculation Block Puzzles. This puzzle involves filling an n×n grid with numbers, ensuring that each row and column contains each number exactly once, following specific rules. It can be thought of as a variation of Sudoku. I have been referring to the rules outlined on the following website for guidance[Number block puzzle](https://www.conceptispuzzles.com/ja/index.aspx?uri=puzzle/calcudoku/rules)
The puzzle generation process involves first creating a Latin square, which serves as the answer, and then randomly dividing an n×n grid into blocks and aligning them with the generated Latin square. I have developed programs for both Latin square generation and block partitioning to facilitate puzzle creation.

Here is an overview of each of the programs:

Latin Square Generation Class:
This program is responsible for generating Latin squares.

Block Partitioning Program:
This program is designed to partition an n×n grid into blocks.

I hope this clarifies the context of my project.

**code**

```
class GridGraph:
  
    def __init__(self, n, latin_square, seed=None):  # If no seed value is specified, the current time is used as the seed
        random.seed(seed)
        self.n = n
        self.G = nx.grid_2d_graph(n, n)
        pos = dict((n, n) for n in self.G.nodes())
        nx.set_node_attributes(self.G, pos, 'pos')  # Add coordinates to node attributes
        for edge in self.G.edges():
            self.G.edges[edge]['weight'] = random.random()
        self.latin_square = latin_square
                
    def limit_nodes(self, l):
        T = nx.minimum_spanning_tree(self.G)
        largest_nodelist_T = max(nx.connected_components(T), key=len)
        while len(largest_nodelist_T) > l:
            H = T.subgraph(largest_nodelist_T)
            edges = list(H.edges())
            # Sort edges based on weight
            edges.sort(key=lambda x: H.edges[x]['weight'])
            e = edges[0]  # Select the edge with the smallest weight
            T.remove_edge(e[0], e[1])
            largest_nodelist_T = max(nx.connected_components(T), key=len)
        self.G = T
        return self.G
        
    def draw_graph(self, title='Graph'):
        """
        Function to draw the graph
        """
        plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
        pos = nx.get_node_attributes(self.G, 'pos')
        # Rotate the position information by 90 degrees
        rotated_pos = {node: (y, -x) for node, (x, y) in pos.items()}
        nx.draw_networkx_edges(self.G, rotated_pos, width=5.0)
        nx.draw_networkx(self.G, pos=rotated_pos, with_labels=True)
        nx.draw_networkx_nodes(self.G, rotated_pos, node_size=800)
        plt.suptitle(title)
        plt.show()
        
    def draw_graph2(self, title='Graph'):  # Display the puzzle
        """
        Function to draw the graph
        """
        plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
        
        for component in nx.connected_components(self.G):
            # Calculate the sum of values in the connected component
            component_sum = sum(self.latin_square.square[i][j] for (i, j) in component)
            # Get the minimum coordinates of the connected component
            min_i, min_j = min(component)
            # Draw the sum at the minimum coordinates of the connected component
            plt.text(min_j, min_i, component_sum, fontsize=20, color='blue', ha='left', va='top')
            # Draw the contours of the connected component
            for i, j in component:
                # If there are no connected component elements above, draw a line segment x=[j,j+1], y=i
                if (i-1, j) not in component:
                    plt.plot([j, j+1], [i, i], color='black')
                else:
                    plt.plot([j, j+1], [i, i], linestyle='dashed', color='lightgray')
                # If there are no connected component elements below, draw a line segment x=[j,j+1], y=i+1
                if (i+1, j) not in component:
                    plt.plot([j, j+1], [i+1, i+1], color='black')
                else:
                    plt.plot([j, j+1], [i+1, i+1], linestyle='dashed', color='lightgray')
                # If there are no connected component elements to the left, draw a line segment x=j, y=[i,i+1]
                if (i, j-1) not in component:
                    plt.plot([j, j], [i, i+1], color='black')
                else:
                    plt.plot([j, j], [i, i+1], linestyle='dashed', color='lightgray')
                # If there are no connected component elements to the right, draw a line segment x=j+1, y=[i,i+1]
                if (i, j+1) not in component:
                    plt.plot([j+1, j+1], [i, i+1], color='black')
                else:
                    plt.plot([j+1, j+1], [i, i+1], linestyle='dashed', color='lightgray')
                    
        # Set axis limits

        # Remove x and y-axis labels
        plt.xticks([])
        plt.yticks([])
        # Invert the y-axis
        plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
        plt.suptitle(title, fontname="MS Gothic")
        plt.title('+', fontsize=20, loc='Right')
        plt.show()
        
    def draw_graph3(self, title='Graph'):  # Display puzzle solutions
        """
        Function to draw the graph
        """
        plt
```

I have already completed the puzzle generation program. My current task is to develop a solver to determine whether the generated puzzle has a unique solution or multiple solutions. It's not necessary to find all solutions; just determining whether there is one or more solutions is sufficient.

As an approach for the solver, I am interested in using Zero-suppressed Binary Decision Diagrams (ZDDs). I would greatly appreciate any specific advice or algorithms for implementing this.

I have already implemented a method to determine isolated cells. I am now looking for guidance on the subsequent steps.
**code**

```
class Board:
    def __init__(self,gridgraph=None):
        self.grid_graph = grid_graph
        self.n = grid_graph.n if grid_graph else None
        
        
    
    def find_single_node_components(self):
        

        single_node_components = [c for c in nx.connected_components(self.grid_graph.G) if len(c) == 1]
        
 
        single_node = [node for component in single_node_components for node in component]
        
        return single_node
    
    def decide_single_node(self,title):
        plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
        
        for component in nx.connected_components(self.grid_graph.G):
 
            component_sum = sum(self.grid_graph.latin_square.square[i][j] for (i, j) in component)

            if  len(component) == 1:
                (i, j) = component.pop()
                plt.text(j+0.5,i+0.6,component_sum,fontsize=40,color='red',ha='center',va='center')
                component.add((i,j))
            min_i, min_j = min(component)

            plt.text(min_j, min_i, component_sum, fontsize=20, color='blue', ha='left', va='top')

            for i, j in component:
        
                if (i-1, j) not in component:
                    plt.plot([j, j+1], [i, i], color='black')
                else:
                    plt.plot([j, j+1], [i, i], linestyle='dashed',color='lightgray')
    
                if (i+1, j) not in component:
                    plt.plot([j, j+1], [i+1, i+1], color='black')
                else:
                    plt.plot([j, j+1], [i+1, i+1], linestyle='dashed',color='lightgray')
          
                if (i, j-1) not in component:
                    plt.plot([j, j], [i, i+1], color='black')
                else:
                     plt.plot([j, j], [i, i+1], linestyle='dashed',color='lightgray')
         
                if (i, j+1) not in component:
                    plt.plot([j+1, j+1], [i, i+1], color='black')
                else:
                    plt.plot([j+1, j+1], [i, i+1], linestyle='dashed',color='lightgray')
                    

        plt.xticks([])
        plt.yticks([])

        plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
        plt.suptitle(title,fontname="MS Gothic")
        
        
        plt.title('+',fontsize=20, loc='Right')

        plt.show()
```

Comment: I didn't see anything in the code that looks like a ZDD, do you not use them at all yet?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please read [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). "please help me" is [not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question); we don't write code to specification. [You are expected to study the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) ahead of time; think of logical steps to solve the problem; figure out exactly where you are stuck, and be able to show exact input and output.

Comment: I apologize for my unfamiliarity with Q&A sites like this. After reading a book that introduced ZDD-based solving techniques for puzzles like Slitherlink and Numberlink, I thought these techniques could be applied to this puzzle as well. However, I'm struggling to come up with how to extend it to the Number Block Puzzle. I would appreciate any advice or algorithms you can provide

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Open ended and opinion based questions that boil down to subjective responses are generally not a good fit for this site, since there generally is not a single correct answer but a range of opinions based on different approaches. Give a good read over [Where to Start](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367), and [mre] then edit your post.